# vue refresh the page only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, location, reload

Is it possible to reload a page when it is created or mounted or something similar?
let me explain, I would like that when a page is loaded, we must activate `location.reload()`; but if I do it on `created()`, or on `mounted()` I get a loop loading.
instead I would like to reload only the first time, so I enter that page and the page reloads only once.

I tried with:

```
 created() {
   if(this.reloaded == false) {
       location.reload();
       this.reloaded = true;
   }
 },
 data() {
   return {
     reloaded: false,
   };
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're reloading the page, you can't store the state within the Vue instance. Instead, you can store it in local storage:

```js
export default {
 created() {
   const reloaded = localStorage.getItem('reloaded');
   if (reloaded !== 'true') {
       localStorage.setItem('reloaded', 'true');
       location.reload();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I would add a localStorage.removeItem('reloaded') on destroyed